# Adding Elements inside a div makes other disappear

Tags: css

I'm trying to create this sort of a card that contains the input + todos.
Expectation : having some sort of a default starting height that'll expand depending on the content (aka, depending on the amount of todos added)

Reality :
Either i set the height for 100% and it works fine, but I can't set the default height.
or i set the height for a random vh number and i can't see all of the content when i scroll.

Is there a way for me to set a default height that'll change when i add content that surpasses the height?

the css code :

```
.card {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -10%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 20vh;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  display: flex;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.addtodo {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

the code :

```
    <div>
      <div className={classes.card}>
        <div className={classes.addtodo}>
          <AddTodo
            onAddHandler={onAddHandler}
            deleteAllTodos={deleteAllTodos}
          />
        </div>
        {todos.map((todo) => {
          return (
            <div className={classes.actions}>
              <Todo name={todo.name} />
              <button onClick={() => deleteTodoHandler(todo.id, todo.name)}>
                X
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => setTodoEditing(todo.id)}>Edit</button>
              {todoEditing === todo.id ? (
                <form>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => setEditedText(e.target.value)}
                  />
                  <button onClick={() => editTodoHandler(todo.id)}>v</button>
                </form>
              ) : (
                <div></div>
              )}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
```

thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: What you want is min-height.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the pixel you want by adding the min-height value to the .card class.

Example;

```
min-height:20px
```

Answer (score 0):

I would either use `min-height` or `clamp` instead of the height property.

With min-height you can just specify a value and the element will stick to that until the content needs more room.

```css
.card {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

With clamp you can specify a minimum value, a desired (usually relative) value, and a maximum value. The desired value will be adopted until min value or max value are not reached.

```css
.card {
  height: clamp(100px, 50vh, 300px)
}
```

Cheers

Comment: What happens is that the elements are being added from the bottom, and whatever I add (todos) go to the top and is being lost inside the element (card).